# Postfix warning: SASL: Connect to /var/spool/postfix/private/auth failed: No such file or directory

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sasl

I have searched, and failed to find an answer and I am out of ideas. I just do not know enough about postfix and dovecot to parse the configs or understand what may be causing this error.

```
warning: SASL: Connect to /var/spool/postfix/private/auth failed: No such file or directory
fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
```

I am unable to connect with external clients (eg. Thunderbird) to postfix using SASL. I am hoping it is something obvious, but I just cannot see it.

1. `/var/spool/postfix/private/auth` exists. It is owned by postfix. Dovecot is set to use postfix as the user
2. Dovecot is running and listening:
   `unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     241906   12768/dovecot        /var/spool/postfix/private/auth`
3. `postconf -n` output:

   ```
   alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
   alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
   append_dot_mydomain = no
   biff = no
   broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
   compatibility_level = 2
   inet_interfaces = all
   inet_protocols = all
   local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
   local_transport = virtual
   mailbox_size_limit = 0
   milter_default_action = accept
   milter_protocol = 2
   mydestination = $myhostname, my-server.my-server.com, my-server, localhost.localdomain, localhost
   myhostname = my-server
   mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
   myorigin = /etc/mailname
   non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
   readme_directory = no
   recipient_delimiter = +
   relay_domains = $mydestination, proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf
   relayhost =
   smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
   smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
   smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
   smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
   smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
   smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
   smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
   smtpd_sasl_path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
   smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
   smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
   smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.my-server.com/fullchain.pem
   smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.my-server.com/privkey.pem
   smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
   smtpd_use_tls = yes
   virtual_alias_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf, proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
   virtual_gid_maps = static:113
   virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vmail
   virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
   virtual_mailbox_limit = 512000000
   virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
   virtual_minimum_uid = 113
   virtual_transport = virtual
   virtual_uid_maps = static:113
   ```
4. `dovecot -n` output:

   ```
   # 2.2.33.2 (d6601f4ec): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
   # Pigeonhole version 0.4.21 (92477967)
   # OS: Linux 4.15.0-66-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS ext4
   auth_mechanisms = plain login
   first_valid_uid = 113
   log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
   login_greeting = My Mail Server
   mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vmail/%u/
   mail_max_userip_connections = 50
   mail_plugins = " zlib"
   mail_privileged_group = mail
   namespace inbox {
     inbox = yes
     location =
     mailbox Drafts {
       special_use = \Drafts
     }
     mailbox Junk {
       special_use = \Junk
     }
     mailbox Sent {
       special_use = \Sent
     }
     mailbox "Sent Messages" {
       special_use = \Sent
     }
     mailbox Spam {
       special_use = \Junk
     }
     mailbox Trash {
       special_use = \Trash
     }
     prefix =
     type = private
   }
   passdb {
     driver = pam
   }
   passdb {
     args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
     driver = sql
   }
   plugin {
     zlib_save = gz
     zlib_save_level = 6
   }
   protocols = imap pop3
   service auth {
     group = postfix
     unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
       group = postfix
       mode = 0666
       user = postfix
     }
     unix_listener auth-userdb {
       group = postfix
       mode = 0666
       user = postfix
     }
     user = postfix
   }
   service imap-login {
     inet_listener imaps {
       port = 993
       ssl = yes
     }
   }
   service imap {
     executable = imap
   }
   ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.my-server.com/fullchain.pem
   ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
   ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
   userdb {
     driver = passwd
   }
   userdb {
     args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
     driver = sql
   }
   protocol imap {
     mail_plugins = " zlib imap_zlib"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

In some distros, like Debian, postfix runs in a chroot by default.  Chroot changes the apparent root directory, so postfix won't see your filesystem as you do. This is why it doesn't see `/var/spool/postfix/private/auth` even though the file exists and it is owned by postfix.

If you want to run postfix without chroot, edit your `/etc/postfix/master.cf` to set the chroot column explicitly to `n` for each relevant item (that's all of them, for me). Note that if you use the implicit default `-` you may still get chroot, apparently due to compilation defaults changed by some distro maintainers.

/etc/postfix/[master.cf](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html):

```
# =============================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# =============================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

If you prefer chrooted operation, see the documentation for preparing posfix for chroot: [BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README#chroot_setup](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#chroot_setup)